# Android watchface: how to know if a peek card is shown and to what height?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-cards, watchface

How does one call the information that a card is being displayed and to what height it is being displayed.

I'm working on a balanced ternary clock, and I'd like to resize the face depending on cards.

Edit: I found a solution.

```
// detect the height of a card. And call resizers.
// baseLedge is the default bottom of the watch
// tallness is the height of the display
// tallable is the portion of the screen height offered to the face.
// ledge is the adjusted bottom of the watch
// ledgeSpace is a desired margin above the ledge
// puff is the ratio of the adjusted display to the standard display
// puffer() is a module (or method or whatever the correct term is) that applies the resizing.
    // no clue what the Override wrapper does or how it work.   
    @Override
    // Rect -> none
    public void onPeekCardPositionUpdate(Rect bounds) {
        super.onPeekCardPositionUpdate(bounds);
        if (!bounds.equals(mCardBounds)) {
            mCardBounds.set(bounds);
            if (bounds.top == 0){bounds.top = (int)tallness;}
            if (bounds.top < baseLedge || ledge != baseLedge) {
                ledge = Math.min(bounds.top, baseLedge);
                puff = (ledge - dispTop -) / tallable; 
                if (puff < (float).25) {puff = (float).25; }
                puffer ();
            }
            invalidate(); // redraw screen without updating time.
        }
    }
```

note: make a flag and find the height the following code could be placed in onPeekCardPositionUpdate()

```
yesCard = bounds.top != (int)0; // boolean that will be true if a card is showing.
cardHeight = (float)bounds.top;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about [peek cards](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/issues.html#PeekCards)? If so, obtaining its dimensions are documented at that link.

Comment: Thank you, I was asking about peek cards. I'm new to java and android so the developer walk throughs don't help me so much. I wish they offered more code examples, or that I was better at finding the code examples that they do offer.

Comment: I did find a sample code which worked for me at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/CardBoundsWatchFaceService.java